# Why does Scala implicit conversion work here with two args but not with one?

Tags: scala

On object ValueSet, I have `apply(pairs : (String, ValueBase)*)` and implicit conversions from Int and String to ValueBase. If I apply `ValueSet("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)` then the pairs of `(String, Int)` convert to `(String, ValueBase)` and it works fine. If I apply with only one pair, `ValueSet("a" -> 1)` then it says there's no overload of apply for `(String,Int)` i.e. it will not implicitly convert. I can hack around this by adding `apply[V <% ValueBase](p : (String, V))` which works in the one-pair case.

Why doesn't `apply(pairs : (String, ValueBase)*)` work with just one pair?

(Bonus question: adding the extra apply() seems to solve the problem - is there a better solution? Is there anything wrong with this solution?)

Here's a complete compilable example, simplified from my actual code to try to show the minimum problem.

```
class ValueBase

case class ValueInt(val value : Int) extends ValueBase
case class ValueString(val value : String) extends ValueBase

case class ValuePair(val key : String, val value : ValueBase)
case class ValueSet(val value : List[ValuePair]) extends ValueBase

object ValueSet {
    def apply(pairs : (String, ValueBase)*) : ValueSet = {
        ValueSet(pairs.map(p => ValuePair(p._1, p._2)).toList)
    }

    /* Commenting out this apply() means single-pair 
     *     ValueSet("a" -> 1)
     * will not compile, error is:
     *     overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   (value: List[ValuePair])ValueSet <and>   (pairs: (String, ValueBase)*)ValueSet  cannot be applied to ((java.lang.String, Int))
     * Why does (String,Int) implicit convert to (String,ValueBase) if there are two args but not if there's one?
     * Why do I need this apply()? 
     */
    def apply[V <% ValueBase](p : (String, V)) : ValueSet = {
        ValueSet(List(ValuePair(p._1, p._2)))
    }
}

object Sample {
    implicit def int2value(i : Int) = ValueInt(i)
    implicit def string2value(s : String) = ValueString(s)

    /* These samples show the goal, to construct the sets
     * in a nice Map-literal sort of style
     */
    val oneInt = ValueSet("a" -> 1)
    val oneString = ValueSet("b" -> "c")
    val twoInt = ValueSet("d" -> 2, "e" -> 3)
    val twoTypes = ValueSet("f" -> 4, "g" -> "quick brown fox")

    /* Taking ArrowAssoc out of the picture and typing "Pair"
     * explicitly doesn't seem to matter 
     */
    val oneInt2 = ValueSet(Pair("a", 1))
    val twoTypes2 = ValueSet(Pair("f", 4), Pair("g", "quick brown fox"))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, as explained by Daniel Sobral in a comment, because “the compiler sees one argument, two apply methods which may take one argument, and the argument passed fits neither. It then *gives up* considering anything else, because it doesn't know which method to try. If two arguments are passed, then one apply is discarded and the compiler looks for implicit conversions that make the other one work.”

(Remember that one `apply` is automatically defined by the compiler, because you're defining a `case class`.)

If you write this instead, implicit conversion works:

```
object ValueSet {
  def fromPairs(pairs: (String, ValueBase)*): ValueSet = {
    ValueSet(pairs.map(p => ValuePair(p._1, p._2)).toList)
  }
}

object Sample {
  implicit def int2value(i: Int): ValueInt = ValueInt(i)
  implicit def string2value(s: String): ValueString = ValueString(s)

  /* These samples show the goal, to construct the sets
   * in a nice Map-literal sort of style
   */
  val oneInt = ValueSet.fromPairs("a" -> 1)
  val oneString = ValueSet.fromPairs("b" -> "c")
  val twoInt = ValueSet.fromPairs("d" -> 2, "e" -> 3)
  val twoTypes = ValueSet.fromPairs("f" -> 4, "g" -> "quick brown fox")
}
```

Not exactly what you were hoping for, I know...

Comment: Interesting. I don't understand why the compiler-defined apply() messes this up :-/ It doesn't seem like Pair("a"->1) should have any way to become a List[ValuePair] so the compiler-defined apply() shouldn't be used... Is the issue that given two single-arg apply() overloads, the compiler gives up on implicit conversion? But then why does adding the extra apply() fix it - maybe because it doesn't need implicit conversion to match the overload, due to "<%" ?

Comment: @Havoc Jean-Philippe hit it spot on. The problem here is that the compiler sees one argument, two `apply` methods which may take one argument, and the argument passed fits neither. It then *gives up* considering anything else, because it doesn't know which method to try. If two arguments are passed, then one `apply` is discarded and the compiler looks for implicit conversions that make the other one work. @Jean, could you complement the answer with this information?

Comment: @Havoc I don't exactly know either. The pages of the Scala specification on overloading resolution are not exactly an easy part. Don't know either why the extra `apply` fixes it, but keep in mind that the view bound `T <% S` is a shorthand for an implicit parameter representing a conversion from `T` to `S`, so it also needs an implicit lookup at compile time.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot for the added explanations, I'll include them right away!

Comment: Do I have this right: the extra apply() with "<%" moves the implicit conversion "inside" the apply(), after an overloaded flavor of apply() has been selected, while without the extra apply() we would need to implicitly convert prior to selecting an overload. The core issue is: overload selection happens before implicit conversion.

Comment: Anyone see a problem with adding the extra apply(), rather than renaming the method to fromPairs ? The extra apply gives prettier syntax ...

Comment: @Havoc Well, yes and no. When you use `V <% ValueBase`, you are saying _any_ `V` applies -- so `Int` can apply just like any other method. It _also_ makes an additional implicit parameter requirement, which is dealt with later. Anyway, yes, overload selection happens before implicit conversion.

Comment: @Daniel Did you read the spec, the compiler code, or both end to end to know all this? It's impressive! :-)

Comment: @Jean Just plain experience, and hanging out (on irc anyway) with the right people. You pay close attention to anything paulp says, and you'll learn a lot about Scala.